# How to change a string to Unicode in Python 2?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have a string like `s1 = "\xed\xf3\xb4\x90"`.

```
>>> x = u"\xed\xf3\xb4\x90"
>>> print x
íó´
```

How could I use `s1` to print this?

I have tried:

```
s1= "\xed\xf3\xb4\x90"
print unicode(s1)
```

But I could not get `íó´`. How could I get `íó´`?

Comment: What is the last character (0x90)??? It's not defined in cp1252 (aka the usual suspect). Do you have any backstory on the 3-character string? Possible encoding?

Answer (score 7):

The correct codec to be used here is `'latin1'`:

```
>>> s1= "\xed\xf3\xb4\x90"
>>> print s1.decode('latin1')  # same as: unicode(s1, 'latin1')
íó´
```

---

However using `'unicode-escape'` also works here as `'unicode-escape'` assumes the bytes are encoded in `'latin1'` and there are no unicode escapes in the OP's string:

```
>>> s1= "\xed\xf3\xb4\x90"
>>> print s1.decode('unicode-escape')  # same as: unicode(s1, 'unicode-escape')
íó´
```

Comment: `len("\xed\xf3\xb4\x90")` -> 4, not 16. Your remark (sub-string "\xed" is treated as series of characters '\', 'x', 'e', 'd') is not true

Comment: This works only because `unicode-escape` assumes the bytes are encoded in `latin1`.  There are no Unicode escapes in the OP's string and the correct codec to use is `latin1`.

Comment: @rongdong.bai Please accept [JohnMachin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41531349/2063361) as he is the one who mentioned correct  codec

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can decode the `str` with the `latin1` codec.