# How do I convert a string formatted like unicode into unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a variable with the string '\u96e8' and I want to convert this to unicode, because the function kanji_to_romaji() only accepts unicode. How would I do this? I am on python 2.7

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from kanji_to_romaji import kanji_to_romaji
message = '\u96e8'
message = unicode(message)
x = kanji_to_romaji(message)
print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a string to Unicode in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530980/how-to-change-a-string-to-unicode-in-python-2)

Comment: The proposed duplicate deals with recovering a Unicode string from a valid encoding, not from a Python literal.

Comment: Given the problems in my answer, the best solution is to avoid having such a string in the first place. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> message = '\u96e8'
>>> ast.literal_eval('u"{}"'.format(message))
u'\u96e8'
```

The trick is to construct a string containing a `unicode` string literal to pass as the argument to `literal_eval`. That is, `u"\u96e8"` rather than just `\u96e8`.

(This is only partially correct, though. It will fail if the value of `message` itself contains a double-quote. There are probably other cases where this fails as well.)

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the bytestring to unicode using the *unicode-escape* codec.

```
>>> message = '\u96e8'
>>> unicode_message = message.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> unicode_message
u'\u96e8'
>>> print unicode_message
雨
```