# Convert string to unicode pyton2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to convert a string to `unicode`, I am able to do that in `python3` but not in `python2.7`.

```py
# unicode string
string = 'pythön!'
# print string
print('The string is:', string)
# default encoding to utf-8
string_utf = string.encode()
# print result
print('The encoded version is:', string_utf)
```

The error is:

```
('The string is:', 'pyth\xc3\xb6n!')
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 4, in <module>
    string_utf = string.encode("utf8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4:         ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Might this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530980/how-to-change-a-string-to-unicode-in-python-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Amol Bais, the answer is:

```
string = 'pythön!'
print('The string is:', string)
string_utf = string.decode('unicode-escape')
print('The encoded version is:', string_utf)
```